# Where is MPV save state location?

Tags: mpv-media-player

Where does `mpv` save or log the state when using `--save-position-on-quit` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>?

This is used to save the exit state in order for the video to start playing from where it was left off when exiting `mpv`.

Comment: I did look at the man page, it only describes the behaviour not the location it is saved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my own copy of mpv:

```
andrew@ilium~$ mpv --version | head -n 1
mpv 0.35.0-255-g16f0cd546d Copyright © 2000-2023 mpv/MPlayer/mplayer2 projects
```

the 'saved' exit state is written in a simple text file in  `$HOME/.config/mpv/watch_later`. An example, again taken from my own system, is:

```
andrew@ilium~/.config/mpv/watch_later$ ls
3F33858724ABD9E42AB6EDA66A77E92D
andrew@ilium~/.config/mpv/watch_later$ cat 3F33858724ABD9E42AB6EDA66A77E92D 
start=15.807474
andrew@ilium~/.config/mpv/watch_later$
```

I note that the [man pages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/mpv.1.html) give some clear detail on this:

```
~/.config/mpv/watch_later/

Contains  temporary  config  files  needed  for resuming playback
of files with the watch later feature. See for example the Q key 
binding, or  the  quit-watch-later input command.

Each file is a small config file which is loaded if the corresponding
media file is loaded. It contains the playback position and some
(not necessarily  all)  settings that  were changed during playback.
The filenames are hashed from the full paths of the media files. It's
in general not possible to extract the  media  filename  from this
hash. However, you can set the --write-filename-in-watch-later-config
option, file.
```

The option `--write-filename-in-watch-later-config` mentioned there is worth using; on my system this command:

```
mpv --save-position-on-quit --write-filename-in-watch-later-config test.avi
```

gives the following result:

```
andrew@ilium~/.config/mpv/watch_later$ cat 3F33858724ABD9E42AB6EDA66A77E92D 
# test.avi
start=26.067734
andrew@ilium~/.config/mpv/watch_later$
```

It would be a great idea to add these options to [the mpv.conf file](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/etc/mpv.conf), as I have done on my system...

Comment: Note that the default recently changed to `~/.local/state/mpv/`